# How to find out if row has date range between another row for same item?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerpivot

So I have data like the following: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWDRD.jpg).
What I'm trying to find out is how many ids are running at the same time for type a and type b.

My current formula is

```
IF(c2=c3,IF(d2<>d3,IF(AND(A2>=a3,A2>=b3),"Not the Same","Same"),""),"")
```

This heavily relies on the sorting which I don't trust as there is most likely something the formula won't be able to account for such as 3 Ids coming up in the data.

I was trying to make a pivot to do the same thing but I was unable to get it to function how I needed it to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pivot seems like the way to go. What didn't work with the pivot?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to get the pivot to give me that data. How would I go about getting it that way?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to get the pivot to give me that data. How would I go about getting it that way? I tried putting them all as rows, putting start date as column and end date as rows and vice versa. The main issue I'm having is with the type variation. There's only 2 types but each type can have multiple start dates.

Comment: I didn't see how a pivot would help very much - the awkward bit is testing if the dates overlap. Have done an answer but not sure how to interpret empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if helper columns are allowed. I've put in a helper column in column F

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,"<="&E2,E$1:E1,">="&A2,C$1:C1,C2,D$1:D1,"<>"&D2)*(COUNTIFS(C$1:C1,C2,F$1:F1,">0")=0)>0,1,0)
```

Basically it checks if the dates overlap with any other row for the same ID but with a different type, and also checks that the match with a different type hasn't already been counted.

Also I've set all the blank dates to today() in column E with a simple formula

```
=IF(B2="",TODAY(),B2)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Those blank spots should be interpreted as Today().

Here is a screenshot of what the data looks like instead of just those 5 rows. http://imgur.com/a/b8mxE

Some ID's have multiple type b's and can have multiple type A's too eg. Example 97 has 2 type B's and 1 type A.

Alternatively, it can have 1 Type B but several type A's (eg. Example 142). http://imgur.com/a/aeOiA

Comment: ignore the column structure, I just put it that way right now in order so I can look at at the Ids quickly for example purposes.

Comment: Is the end date always blank?

Comment: It's only blank if it's still active/processing. There's just a lot of things that are still running and therefore blank. The ones that are in there as both Type A & B are the ones that need to be counted.

Comment: I think I'll have to put another helper column to substitute today() for blank dates then because otherwise you would have to use Array formulae I think and it might be slow if you have a lot of data - I would prefer to stick with Countifs